# Maximum header value allowed in Sun One web server 6.1

Tags: sunone

I'm getting 413 (Request entity too large) response from sunone web server (version 6.1).when i check the size of the request header, its 4588 bytes. Is there a maximum allowed size for HTTP header in SunOne? If so is it possible to change the value?